# Why won't my page go to the next in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Ok this is an app i am trying to build. I want it to go from the ActivityMain to the second page when i click a button. BUT it won't load the next page.

This is the first page (MainActivity.java) it controls the xml file fn_main.xml.

To save time and space i will explain the xml files here. 
fn_main.xml has a textview and a listview. Simple enough.

```
package com.example.boonehallfrightnightsapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] CHOICES = new String[]
            {
                "Haunted House",
                "Amy's Nightmare",
                "Zombie Town",
                "Haunted Hayride",
                "Quit"
            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fn_main);

         //found this part on an example
         //Set up ArrayAdaptor for the options
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CHOICES));
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      //part of example  
      //Set up the listener for user clicks on the list
        setListClickListener();

        //this toast is for when it opens
        Toast.makeText(this, "yo whats up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


     private void setListClickListener()
        {
            //Set up the click listener for the options
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener
            (
                new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    //@Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                    {
                        switch(arg2)
                        {
                            case 0: launchHousePage();
                                    break;
                            case 1: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 2: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 3: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 4: finish();
                                    break;
                            default: break;
                        }
                    }
                }//END OnItemClickListener
            );//END setOnItemClickListener
        }//END setListClickListener

     //Just added this to open the new page
     protected void launchHousePage()
        {
            //Set up Intent
            Intent launchHouse = new Intent(this, House.class);
            startActivity(launchHouse);

        }//END launchDirectionsPage
     ///goes nuts after this is played. 
}
```

now that is the end of that. This page will load and do very well if i click the other options. But i want it to go to my next xml/java files.

This page is House.java, and it controls the xml file part_list.xml.

Part_list.xml has the same things as before, but with a button on the end.

My problem is I don't know if this page is the problem or my code in the last method in main was the problem. Or is it the listview going to another listview.

```
package com.example.boonehallfrightnightsapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class House extends ListActivity 
{


    //Array of choices for user
        static final String[] CHOICES = new String[]
        {
            "Welcome Hos",
            "Line Divider",
            "Drop Window 1",
            "Gargoyle",
            "Arch Hall Statue",
            "Iron Smith",
            "Hooping Creature",
            "Kitchen Hag",
            "Beast Operator",
            "Torture Cell Victim",
            "Stretch door",
            "Executioner Room",
            "Drop Window 2",
            "Overhead Creature",
            "Impailer Keeper",
            "Demon Druid 1",
            "Demon Druid 2",
            "Chainsaw 1",
            "Chainsaw 2"
        };

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.part_list);

            //Set Back button listener to get user's name
            setDoneButtonListener();

            //Set up ArrayAdaptor for the options
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CHOICES));
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

          //part of example  
          //Set up the listener for user clicks on the list
            setListClickListener();

            //this toast is for when it opens
            Toast.makeText(this, "you can't handle this fear", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }//end onCreate

        private void setDoneButtonListener()
        {
            Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
            doneButton.setOnClickListener
            (
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        close();
                    }

                    private void close() 
                    {

                        finish();
                    }
                }
            );//END setOnClickListener
        }//END setDoneButtonListener

        private void setListClickListener()
        {
            //Set up the click listener for the options
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener
            (
                new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    //@Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                    {
                        switch(arg2)
                        {
                            case 0: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 1: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 2: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 3: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 4: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 5: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 6: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 7: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 8: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 9: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 10: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 11: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 12: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 14: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 15: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 16: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 17: finish();
                                    break;
                            case 18: finish();
                                    break;
                            default: break;
                        }
                    }
                }//END OnItemClickListener
            );//END setOnItemClickListener
        }//END setListClickListener

}
```

after testing some stuff i found this is the problem. but how do i fix what is going on. 
This code is found on the mainactivity.java page.

```
protected void launchHousePage()
            {
                //Set up Intent
                Intent launchHouse = new Intent(this, House.class);
                startActivity(launchHouse);

            }//END launchDirectionsPage
```

OK so when i go to the House.java page I use public class House extends ListActivity  instead extends Activity.

So if I want to have a listview on the house page how would i do that....?

Comment: What does "it won't load the next page" mean?  What **exactly** happens.  You've dumped lots of code and XML but you haven't explained the problem.

Comment: check whether setListClickListener() is called or not using logger

Comment: it crashes to be exact.

Comment: @KamleshArya I can't make any sense of the logger info. Should i post that up too?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your AndroidManifest.xml file contains your `House` activity. Is your `setContentView` method calling the right layout in your House.java?

Comment: this was only part of the problem. I got that fixed (forgot to add to the manifest file.) But now i got the main just of the problem. see the update

Answer (score 1):

```
So if I want to have a listview on the house page how would i do that....?
```

When you extend ListActivity, a default ListView is created for you. You access it using the android.R.id.list. Other way is to have this piece of code in the XML file used by the respective Activity (i think it's House.java here):

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

The id has to be @android:id/list and nothing else if you are extending ListActivity.

HTH

Comment: yes but how would this work if i can't use the extend ListActivity.

Comment: The problem right now is one list view is going to another one on a new page.